# How to change the default batch size of Keras layers when compiling a model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, triplet

I have a simple model in Keras 2.8.0 that takes a batch of images and outputs the pairwise distance of their embeddings:

```
inp = layers.Input((28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(inp)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Lambda(lambda y: K.sum((y-y[:, None])**2, axis=-1))(x)
model = models.Model(inp, x)
```

It works well when the batch size is less than or equal to 32, for example:

```
X = np.random.rand(32, 28, 28, 1).astype(np.float32)
model.predict(X).shape
# (32, 32)
```

However, when the batch size is greater than 32, I get an error:

```
X = np.random.rand(40, 28, 28, 1).astype(np.float32)
model.predict(X).shape

# InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [32,32] vs. shape[1] = [8,8] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

As I understand it, this is due to the fact that the Keras default layers' batch size is 32. But I haven't found how to change it or make it adaptive to the batch size. How can I change the Keras default batch size when compiling a model?

Comment: It is not about different batch size, pay attention in your last layer i.e. k.sum. Also note, still your code runs in keras 2.11 (tested). Would you mind adding reason on the operation you did in lambda layer?

Comment: You can try adjusting the dimensions of your input data or adjusting the network to handle inputs of different sizes.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the sum. you can change the lambda function to be a layer that calculates the pairwise distance of a vector [B, N] and outputs [B, B]. The thing that it doesnt work with batches over 32.

Comment: Keras layers do not have a default batch size, the batch size is specified in model.fit, I think your operation is the problem as it should work with all batch sizes. Note how the error mentions a concatenation op which is not present in your model.

Comment: you can also change the lambda layer to this: y = layers.Lambda(lambda v: v @ tf.transpose(v))(x)
and it still doesnt work

Comment: Try running your code on latest keras, you can check it on colab.

Comment: I ran in colab, bs=32 returns an array and 34 returns something called tf.RaggedTensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works: `model(X)` returns a `(40, 40)` output.

The true issue is with `model.predict(X)`: the concatenation error (`ConcatOp`) is about the fact that `.predict()` uses a default batch size of `32` (not the Keras layers) and so it's unable to concatenate two lists of shapes: `[32,32]` and `[8,8]`, because your pairwise-distance operation **cannot be split in multiple batches!**

To solve the issue either call `model(X)` or use `model.predict(X, batch_size=len(X))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Keras' Input layer to set the variable input size and then using resize layers like Reshape to adjust the size of intermediate outputs:

```
inp = layers.Input((28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(inp)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Lambda(lambda y: K.sum((K.expand_dims(y, 1)-K.expand_dims(y, 0))**2, axis=-1))(x)
model = models.Model(inp, x)
```

See if I helped you, otherwise come back here.

Comment: inp = layers.Input(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
expects to receive a 5D tensor